# How to put a text like this?

Tags: alignment

I want to align the text in a line, and the words have different sizes.

[image]

For example, "d" is up aligned, "f" is bottom aligned, and "h" is left aligned. Those three words have a smaller size. Other words have a larger size.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "large font" and "small font". (The macros `\large` and `\small` have a very particular meaning in TeX and LaTeX, but somehow I suspect you don't have that meaning in mind.)

Comment: @Mico What I meant is that those words in a line may have different sizes. And, I was planning to align some of those words in different styles.

Comment: And what would these "different sizes" and "different styles" be? (Sorry, but my psychic divination skills are absolutely worthless.)

Comment: @Mico For example, "d" is up aligned, "f" is bottom aligned, and "h" is left aligned. Those three words have a smaller size. Other words have a larger size.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you asked:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{7}{C} X C }
    a&b&c&\textsuperscript{d}&e&\textsubscript{f}&g&\scriptsize{h}&i
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of streamlining your code, e.g., by defining a centered version of the `X` column type and removing the need for all those `@{}` particles. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thank you for doing that @Mico, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Without or with rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newlength{\cellwidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{0.1111\dimexpr(\textwidth-18\tabcolsep)}
\Large
\begin{tabular}{
  *{7}{w{c}{\cellwidth}} 
  w{l}{\cellwidth}
  w{c}{\cellwidth}
}
A & B & C &
\raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A-\height}{\footnotesize d} &
e &
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\fontchardp\font`g+\depth}{\footnotesize f} &
g & \footnotesize h & I
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{0.1111\dimexpr(\textwidth-10\arrayrulewidth-18\tabcolsep)}
\Large
\hspace*{0pt minus 3pt}\begin{tabular}{
  |*{7}{w{c}{\cellwidth}|} 
  w{l}{\cellwidth}|
  w{c}{\cellwidth}|
}
\hline
A & B & C &
\raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A-\height}{\footnotesize d} &
e &
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\fontchardp\font`g+\depth}{\footnotesize f} &
g & \footnotesize h & I \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome.